# Assignment across data types in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make VS compiler catch signed/unsigned assignments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75385/make-vs-compiler-catch-signed-unsigned-assignments)

I've compiled the following snippet of code in VC++ 2005/2008:

```
unsigned long ul = ...;
signed long l = ...;

l = ul;
```

and was expecting to see a compiler warning (Warning Level set to 4), but none was generated. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks

Comment: the only answer is that it's up to the individual compiler what to generate warnings over. And apparently, the VC++ team didn't think this warranted a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a duplicate [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75385/make-vs-compiler-catch-signed-unsigned-assignments).
Quoting the accepted answer:

> You need to enable warning 4365 to catch the assignment.
>   That might be tricky - you need to enable ALL warnings - use /Wall which enables lots of warnings, so you may have some trouble seeing the warning occur, but it does. (quamrana)
>
> > You could also use #pragma warning(default: 4365) to enable. (ChrisN)

Comment: Thank you. They certainly did a good job of hiding this option!

Answer (score 2):

If the omitted initializers are compile-time constants, the static analyzer may be able to determine that no overflow can occur and let it slide without a warning.  Try initializing ul to something > 2^31 -1 and see what happens (assuming you're on a 32-bit platform).

Comment: I'd actually tried that before. No warnings were generated no matter what border value ul was initialized to.

Answer (score 1):

Warnings are compiler specific. You "should" see a warning in the sense that "it would help you" to see one, but the Visual C++ team did not choose to display one by default.